# Custom Drawing on MKMapview

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, mkmapview

I am working on a map app, in this app i have to show distance between points(start, mid & end). I have attached a screenshot of an existing app, i have to make similar line on map.

[image]

So far i have tried 2 different approaches

Using **MKOverlay**

```
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id < MKOverlay >)overlay{
if(overlay==circle)
{
    MKCircleRenderer *renderer = [[MKCircleRenderer alloc] initWithCircle:overlay];
    renderer.lineWidth = 12;
    renderer.fillColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.8];
    renderer.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    return renderer;
}
MKPolylineRenderer *renderer = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];
if(overlay==backline)
{
    renderer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.85];
    renderer.fillColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
    renderer.lineWidth = 8.0;
    renderer.lineJoin = kCGLineJoinBevel;
}
else if(overlay==line)
{
    renderer.strokeColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.9];
    renderer.fillColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
    renderer.lineWidth = 6.0;
    renderer.lineJoin = kCGLineJoinBevel;
}


return renderer;
```

}

Using UIBezierPath

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(2, 100)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100)];
[path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(100, 100) radius:15 startAngle:0 endAngle:2.0 * M_PI clockwise:YES];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(318, 100)];
[path closePath];
path.lineWidth = 8;
path.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapButt;
[[UIColor blueColor] setStroke];
[path stroke];
```

But the output is same

[image]

The white line is created using MKOverlay and blue line is created using UIBezierPath. As you can see line joint is visible. I want to make it look like the line in 1st screenshot.
Please help me.

Comment: What line joint is visible in the line drawn by the overlay?  Your question is not clear.  Are you asking how to make the circle draggable?

Comment: I want to make the circle look exactly like the 1st screenshot. I have created a line from 'start' to 'mid' and then 'mid' to 'end'. Then a circle on 'mid'. There is a transparent area in the middle of the circle. There line joint is visible, i want to clip that part. like masking. IN the 1st screenshot, line starts at 'start' and merges in a circle on mid.

Comment: Draw your line from start to the circle and then from the other side of the circle to the end. There is just a bit "rule of three" math involved. And don't forget the dot in the middle.